# SizeLimitExceededException not being caught by Spring ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring

On a Java web-app using Spring, When I upload a file bigger than the defined maximum size, a `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException` is thrown.

I expect it to be caught by my custom `ExceptionHandlingController.class` which is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and that successfully catches all the other specific exceptions that I like to treat with some specific logic ; but not ***this one***.

What could cause this problematic behaviour, and how can I fix it ?

The exception is clear :

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (174470507) exceeds the configured maximum (7000000)
```

The max file size is defined like this in my `applicationContext.xml` :

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="7000000" /><!-- amount is in Bytes -->
</bean>
```

The `ExceptionHandlingController` class, with some redactions (can't get nice indent on SO.. :) :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {
private static final Logger NON_SECURITY_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionHandlingController.class);

@ExceptionHandler({MailSendException.class})
public RedirectView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, MailSendException exception) {
           RedirectView rw = new RedirectView("/");
    FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(req);
    outputFlashMap.put(Constants.FLASH_GENERIC, "Our mail service seems to have issues. Please try again or contact an administrator if the problem persists");
    return rw;
}

 // TODO THIS WON'T GET CAUGHT !!!!!!!!!!!!
@ExceptionHandler({FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException.class})
public RedirectView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException exception) {
    RedirectView rw = new RedirectView("/");
    FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(req);
    outputFlashMap.put(Constants.FLASH_GENERIC, "Woops ! The file that you tried to upload is too large. Please respect the rules.");
    return rw;
}

@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) throws Exception {
    NON_SECURITY_LOGGER.log(ERROR, "######### EXCEPTION #########", exception);
    throw exception;
}}
```

in `web.xml` :

```
<filter>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

As a bonus, if I could have the exception thrown WHEN the max file size is reached, instead of after the end of the whole upload, this would be great ; but this should be a separate question :)

Note : I verified that the exception is not caught by the other handlers. It is simply "bypassing" everything.

Thanks for any help ! :)

=== UPDATE / FEEDBACK ON VALIDATED ANSWER ===

As pointed out in the validated answer by Elevate, I simply removed the filter from `web.xml` and switched the bean configuration from `applicationContext.xml` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (pure copy-paste).

Also, the `ExceptionHandlingController` now catches a `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` instead of a `SizeLimitExceededException` due to the rewiring.

The exception is now caught properly ; thanks to Elevate for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked: "What could cause this problematic behaviour?"

The multipart filter is being applied around the controller, so the controller doesn't see the exception. It's not happening inside the controller.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html) for MultipartFilter says that it's designed for use cases where you aren't using Spring's Web MVC:

> Note: This filter is an alternative to using DispatcherServlet's MultipartResolver support, for example for web applications with custom web views which do not use Spring's web MVC, or for custom filters applied before a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet.

You ask, "and how can I fix this?"

The answer is (obviously) to put the multipart handling *inside* the controller. :)

You'll need to remove the filter from `web.xml` and configure a `CommonsMultipartResolver` to run within the scope of the controller. I don't know exactly how your controller is configured, so you'll have to work it out or post another question!

Comment: updated the question with feedback on how it answered the question

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically create the resolver bean by something like this:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class MultipartResolverBeanConfig {

  /**
   * Create the multipart resolver bean
   * Set the maximum upload file size as defined in the configuration file
   * @return the multipartResolver bean
   */
  @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return multipartResolver;
  }
}
```

You are right to change it to `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` but you can also get the `SizeLimitExceededException` out of that too something like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    MaxUploadSizeExceededException musee = (MaxUploadSizeExceededException)ex;
    SizeLimitExceededException slee = musee.getCause() instanceof SizeLimitExceededException ? (SizeLimitExceededException) musee.getCause() : null;
    Long maxSize = slee == null ? musee.getMaxUploadSize() : slee.getPermittedSize();
    Long actualSize = slee == null ? Long.parseLong(request.getHeader("Content-Length")) : slee.getActualSize();

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "error", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, request);
  }
```